# Kazam is not recording audio from Logitech USB headset

Tags: pulseaudio, screencast, kazam

I am trying to record a short screencast using Kazam. Unfortunately, it refuses to record sound from my Logitech USB headset. The Kazam preferences show only "Monitor*" devices. What can I do to make it see the other recording devices?

[image: Kazam preferences and Input Devices volume control]

Answer (score 4):

A trick of PulseAudio could be used as workaround, by creating a *Virtual Sink* and *Loopback* microphone to it.

```
pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=Virtual1    
pactl load-module module-loopback latency_msec=1 sink=Virtual1
```

I just give it a try, after I verified the source code of those combo boxes. **It does record microphone.** The only problem here is "Microphone" and "Speakers" label should be swapped. You may count it as a bug!

Here is, it is already reported & fix released. [lp bug#1184010](https://bugs.launchpad.net/kazam/+bug/1184010)

So:

- Check `Speakers` to record microphone
- Check `Microphone` to record speakers